# Why my browser app will only do google searches and not go to URLs?

Tags: java, webview, textedit

I coded a browser app for Android devices, I added code to pull up URLs when typed in and that works fine. but when I add code that I believe would allow a user to do a google search as well, the app only does google searches.

My goal for the app is for a user to type in the TextEdit either an Url and when the user hits enter it will go to the website and I want it to where a user just types in Cats for example in the TextEdit it does a google search.

The line of code entered is

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            webView.loadUrl("https://" + editText.getText().toString());
            editText.setText("");


        }
    });
```

But when I add the webview element that does a google search it does google searches only

The complete code to my main activity is here

```
<https://github.com/Ramesusxd/Pharaoh/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pharaoh/MainActivity.java>
```

Comment: the line of code where I tried to add that is on line 32 in the mainactivity. when I add that code it only does a google search. how do i make it do either a google search or pull up the URL entered

Comment: Hi are you trying to make it so if user type a word, it will google search for that word; if user type a url, it will load to the url?

Comment: Yes I am thats exactly what Im trying to do. But the code I add it makes it do google searches only even entering an Url

Comment: Hey check out the solution below, do tell us if it works

Comment: I deeply apologize i realised I did not have the whole line of code up. i just made the changes in the edit

Comment: so would i be changing it from a public void to a public boolean?

Comment: Nope, keep it as it is, just replace `webView.loadUrl("https://" + editText.getText().toString());` with the one in the solutions, of course you still need to include a check, to determine whether the text entered is a url or not

Comment: ok thank you I will try this right away when I get home from work. and let u know if i have any issues or not

Comment: Do you still having issues with this? If the solution below helped you to get the answer, do mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: yeah im still having issues with this :( cant get a straight answer on how i would be setting up the if else statement to do a URL vs google search.

Comment: Have you check and try the answer below?

Comment: @WilsonSim I tired I had a problem with setting it up to realize its a if/else statement. I could not figure out how to make it call either or

Comment: Pardon? Can you add the code in your question with details? What call you have not figured out?

Answer (score 3):

for this I think you need to set a If-else statement here.

1. Check the text in the editText if it is a url
2. If it is a url, do `webView.loadUrl(editText.getText());`
3. If it is not, do `webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/#q=" + editText.getText());`